# Fetch with Authentication - File Download

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am trying to download a document, with a fetch request that requires authentication. The code itself works and the fetch is successful. However, I don't know what to do with the response since it is not in JSON or text format? It doesn't prompt a download.

Any thoughts?

```
export async function getDocument(authentication, file_link) {

    const url = "https://dtapiuat.datatree.com:443/api/Report/DownloadDocument?fileLink=" + file_link;
    console.log("Retrieve Customer URL: " + url);

    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Authorization': authentication
        },

    })
    .then(async(httpResponse) => {
        if (httpResponse.ok) {
            console.log(httpResponse.ok);
            return httpResponse;
        } else {
            return "Fetch did not succeed";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the output you think you get? And what is the output you want?

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error in your console?

Comment: As @Tvde1 asked, we need to know what the response is. Could you post the results of `console.log(httpResponse)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a URL with Blob and open it.

Something similar to below.

```
download(data){
  var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
  var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

Note - This will not show the progress of file download. If file is huge then you may need to show manual progress bar.